# Non domain access error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a database sitting on a domain which is to be used by a VB application.

The domain is not a company wide domain, it is just in use by people at that site.

This application now has to be used by other members of staff who are not on the domain and are not on the same site. When attempting to log into the application the following error message is appearing

```
The Microsoft office access database engine cannot open or write to the file [Database Path] It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data
```

The connection string in the application is

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\ServerIP\Folder\Filename.accdb; persist security info = false;"
```

So I am assuming that this is being blocked by the domain, I have give the folder where the database sits full user permissions for the NETWORK SERVICE user hoping this would fix it but to no avail, so how can I fix it for users to log into the app? Can I make a user on the domain and tell the application to connect as that user? if so can anyone give me an example of some code or point me towards an example? or is there another way to do this that I havent thought of?

Comment: When you say you have given NETWORK SERVICE full user permissions, was you following this, or something similar? http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/01/c-microsoft-office-access-database.html

Comment: @ProNinjaCat Yes, that is the guide I was following.